# How to dynamically load json schema to typescript with webpack

Tags: typescript, webpack, loader, jsonschema

I have a json schema describing an object [Person](http://json-schema.org/examples.html). I would like to be able to load that schema into a typescript file directly this way:

```
import Person from './schema/person.schema.json';
```

For this, I created a loader which convert the json file to a typescript interface declaration (using [json-schema-to-typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-schema-to-typescript)) and then pass the result to ts-loader.

My webpack is configured this way:

**webpack.config.js** (excerpt)

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.ts$/,
      loader: 'ts-loader',
    },
    {
      test: /\.schema\.json$/,
      loader: 'ts-loader!jsonschema-loader',
      exclude: /(node_modules)/,
    },
  ]
},
```

Following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46503615/import-html-from-typescript-with-webpack) I configured a declaration so that the json file is considered a string:

**declaration.d.ts**:

```
declare module '*.schema.json' {
  const schema: string;
  export default schema;
}
```

My loader changes the filename it processes on the fly, so what the ts-loader think it loads is `person.schema.ts`. Moreover, I have checked the result of my loader is correct. Here it is:

```
/**
 * This file was automatically generated by json-schema-to-typescript.
 * DO NOT MODIFY IT BY HAND. Instead, modify the source JSONSchema file,
 * and run json-schema-to-typescript to regenerate this file.
 */

export interface Person {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  /**
   * Age in years
   */
  age?: number;
  [k: string]: any;
}
```

However, when I build my project, Person is not recognized as an object and the compilation fails:

**index.js**

```
import Person from './schema/person.schema.json';

const person: Person = {
  lastName: 'Doe',
  firstName: 'John',
};
console.log(person);
```

compilation fails with:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.ts
(3,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Person'.
```

Although I defines the export of .schema.json file as string in my declaration, my loader dynamically changes the filename (this.resourcePath) to a ts file so the ts-loader should see it as a standard ts file and export the Person object.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: might help, https://stackoverflow.com/q/31173738/794088

Comment: As Person is not a default export, pls try: import { Person } from './schema/person.schema.json';

Comment: @Daniel actually, he needs to `export default interface Person`

Answer (score 3):

**Use `appendTsSuffixTo`**

I think your setup will work if you use `ts-loader`'s [appendTsSuffixTo option](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader#appendtssuffixto-regexp-default), rather than changing the filename yourself in your custom loader.  As noted in comments, you may also need to adjust the way `Person` is being imported or exported.

Using `appendTsSuffixTo`, you'd remove the `this.resourcePath = this.resourcePath + '.ts';` (or similar code) from your loader.  Then adjust your webpack config to something like this:

```
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        options: {
            appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.schema.json$/]
          }
      },
      {
        test: /\.schema\.json$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader!my-own-loader',
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
      },
    ]
  },
```

You can also get rid of `typings.d.ts` using this approach.

**But why?**

It wasn't immediately clear to me why your approach wouldn't work; intuitively it seemed like it should be equivalent to using `appendTsSuffixTo`. So I debugged through `ts-loader` a bit to see what was going on.

If I modify the `resourcePath` myself, things largely look fine in `ts-loader/dist/index.js`, but things start going wrong in `ts-loader/dist/servicesHost.js`.

Specifically, I see `resolveModuleName()` return `undefined` for my `example.schema.json` file when I just change `this.resourcePath` in my loader.  However, I see it resolve correctly when using `appendTsSuffixTo`.

I'm not a contributor to (or expert in) `ts-loader`, but my take on this is that when modifying `this.resourcePath` in the loader, your `.schema.json` file will indeed compile, but then fail to be resolved wherever it is imported.

**Other Considerations**

Getting your webpack build to run is one thing; providing a nice developer experience in an IDE is another.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47343106/2999566) to a closely related question for more thoughts on this, and [this Github repo](https://github.com/mikepatrick/ts-generating-loader) for working sample code that might be helpful.