# Why does webpack --watch invoke my custom loader on unrelated files?

Tags: typescript, webpack, ts-loader, webpack-loader, webpack-watch

I have a simple custom Webpack loader which generates TypeScript code from a `.txt` file:

**txt-loader.js**

```
module.exports = function TxtLoader(txt) {
  console.log(`TxtLoader invoked on ${this.resourcePath} with content ${JSON.stringify(txt)}`)
  if (txt.indexOf('Hello') < 0) {
    throw new Error(`No "Hello" found`)
  }
  return `export const TEXT: string = ${JSON.stringify(txt)}`
}
```

In real life, I'm of doing some parsing on the input; in this example, let's assume that a file must contain the text `Hello` to be valid.

This loader lets me import the text file like this:

**index.ts**

```
import { TEXT } from './hello.txt'

console.log(TEXT)
```

It all works fine, except for one thing: `webpack watch` (and its cousin `webpack serve`). The first compilation is fine:

```
$ /tmp/webpack-loader-repro/node_modules/.bin/webpack watch
TxtLoader invoked on /tmp/webpack-loader-repro/hello.txt with content "Hello world!\n"
asset main.js 250 bytes [compared for emit] [minimized] (name: main)
./index.ts 114 bytes [built] [code generated]
./hello.txt 97 bytes [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.64.3 compiled successfully in 3952 ms
```

But then I change the `hello.txt` file:

```
$ touch hello.txt
```

And suddenly weird stuff happens:

```
TxtLoader invoked on /tmp/webpack-loader-repro/index.ts with content "import { TEXT } from './hello.txt'\n\nconsole.log(TEXT)\n"
TxtLoader invoked on /tmp/webpack-loader-repro/custom.d.ts with content "declare module '*.txt'\n"
[webpack-cli] Error: The loaded module contains errors
    at /tmp/webpack-loader-repro/node_modules/webpack/lib/dependencies/LoaderPlugin.js:108:11
    at /tmp/webpack-loader-repro/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1930:5
    at /tmp/webpack-loader-repro/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/AsyncQueue.js:352:5
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/tmp/webpack-loader-repro/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at AsyncQueue._handleResult (/tmp/webpack-loader-repro/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/AsyncQueue.js:322:21)
    at /tmp/webpack-loader-repro/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/AsyncQueue.js:305:11
    at /tmp/webpack-loader-repro/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1392:15
    at /tmp/webpack-loader-repro/node_modules/webpack/lib/HookWebpackError.js:68:3
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/tmp/webpack-loader-repro/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at Cache.store (/tmp/webpack-loader-repro/node_modules/webpack/lib/Cache.js:107:20)
error Command failed with exit code 2.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

**It seems that Webpack decided to throw more files at my loader than specified in the configuration.**

If I remove the exception throwing in the loader and return some arbitrary valid TypeScript code, the generated `main.js` looks exactly the same. So it seems that these extra operations are entirely redundant. But I don't believe that the right solution is to make my loader swallow those exceptions.

The loader is configured like this:

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: './index.ts',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.txt$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            // Tell TypeScript that the input should be parsed as TypeScript,
            // not JavaScript: <https://stackoverflow.com/a/47343106/14637>
            options: { appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.txt$/] },
          },
          path.resolve('txt-loader.js'),
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

Finally, these are the necessary bits to put it all together:

**custom.d.ts**

```
declare module '*.txt'
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "webpack-loader-repro",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-loader": "9.2.6",
    "typescript": "4.5.2",
    "webpack": "5.64.3",
    "webpack-cli": "4.9.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

For those who want to try this at home, [clone this minimal repro project](https://github.com/ttencate/webpack-loader-repro).

Is this a bug in Webpack? In ts-loader? In my configuration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### 1. The Problem

The main problem is that `ts-loader` will load additional files and manually call your loader on them.

In your current webpack configuration you will end up with 2 independent `ts-loader` instances:

- One for `.ts` files
- And one for `.txt` files

###### 1.1. first compilation

During the initial compilation the following will happen:

- `index.ts` will be handled by the first `ts-loader` instance, which will try to compile it.
- The first `ts-loader` doesn't know how to load a `.txt` file, so it looks around for some module declarations and finds `custom.d.ts` and loads it.
- Now that the first `ts-loader` knows how to deal with `.txt` files, it will register `index.ts` and `custom.d.ts` as dependent on `hello.txt` ([`addDependency` call here](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/blob/55d2a85850674d69af1be603c1218384465fa457/src/index.ts#L428))
- After that the first `ts-loader` instance will ask webpack to please compile `hello.txt`.
- `hello.txt` will be loaded by the second `ts-loader` instance, through your custom loader (like one would expect)

###### 2.1. second compilation

Once you touch (or modify) `hello.txt`, webpack will dutifully notify all watchers that `hello.txt` has changed. But because `index.ts` & `custom.d.ts` are dependent on `hello.txt`, all watchers will be notified as well that those two have changes.

- The first `ts-loader` will get all 3 change events, ignore the `hello.txt` one since it didn't compile that one and do nothing for the `index.ts` & `custom.d.ts` events since it sees that there are no changes.
- The second `ts-loader` will also get all 3 change events, it'll ignore the `hello.txt` change if you just touched it or recompile it in case you edited it. After that it sees the `custom.d.ts` change, realizes that it hasn't yet compiled that one and will try to compile it as well, [while invoking all loaders specified after it](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/blob/55d2a85850674d69af1be603c1218384465fa457/src/watch-run.ts#L80). The same thing happens with the `index.ts` change.
- The reason why the second `ts-loader` even tries to load those files are the following:

  - For `index.ts`: Your `.tsconfig` doesn't specify `include` or `exclude` or `files`, so `ts-loader` will use the default of `["**"]` for `include`, i.e. everything it can find. So once it gets the change notification for `index.ts` it'll try to load it.

    - This also explains why you don't get it with `onlyCompileBundledFiles: true` - because in that case `ts-loader` realizes that it should ignore that file.
  - For `custom.d.ts` it's mostly the same, but they will still be included even with `onlyCompileBundledFiles: true`:

    > The default behavior of ts-loader is to act as a drop-in replacement for the tsc command, so it respects the include, files, and exclude options in your tsconfig.json, loading any files specified by those options. The onlyCompileBundledFiles option modifies this behavior, loading only those files that are actually bundled by webpack, as well as any .d.ts files included by the tsconfig.json settings. .d.ts files are still included because they may be needed for compilation without being explicitly imported, and therefore not picked up by webpack.

###### 1.3. any compilation after that

If you modify your `txt-loader.js` to not throw but rather return the contents unchanged, i.e.:

```js
if (txt.indexOf('Hello') < 0) {
    return txt;
}
```

We can see what happens on the third, fourth, etc... compilation.

Since both `index.ts` & `custom.d.ts` are now in the caches of both `ts-loader`s, your custom loader will only be called if there is an actual change in any of those files.

---

#### 2. Similar issues

You aren't the only one that ran into this "feature", there's even an open github issue for it:

- [custom loader in chain with ts-loader consumes ts files](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/issues/1271)
- [ts-loader breaks webpack serve due to loaderContext reuse](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/issues/1348)
- [Proposal to make ts-loader a better webpack citizen](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/issues/552)

---

#### 3. Potential solutions

There are a few ways you can avoid this problem:

###### 3.1. make the `.txt` `ts-loader` transpile-only

In `transpileOnly: true`-mode `ts-loader` will ignore all other files and only handle those that webpack explicitly asked to compile.

So this would work:

```js
/* ... */
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.txt$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            options: { appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.txt$/], transpileOnly: true },
          },
          path.resolve('txt-loader.js'),
        ],
      },
    ],
/* ... */
```

You'll loose type-checking for your `.txt` files though with this approach.

###### 3.2. make sure there's only one `ts-loader` instance

As long as you specify exactly the same options to each loader, `ts-loader` will reuse the loader instance.

That way you have a shared cache for `*.ts` files and `*.txt` files, so `ts-loader` doesn't try to pass `*.ts` files through your `*.txt` webpack rule.

So the following definition would work as well:

```js
/* ... */
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            options: { appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.txt$/] },
          }
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.txt$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            options: { appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.txt$/] },
          },
          path.resolve('txt-loader.js'),
        ],
      },
    ],
/* ... */
```

###### 3.2.1 using `ts-loader`'s `instance` option

`ts-loader` has a (rather hidden) [`instance`](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader#instance) option.

Normally this would be used to segregate two `ts-loader` instances which have the same options - but it can also be used to forcefully merge two `ts-loader` instances.

So this would work as well:

```js
/* ... */
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            options: { appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.txt$/], instance: "foobar" },
          }
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.txt$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            options: { instance: "foobar", /* OTHER OPTIONS SILENTLY IGNORED */ },
          },
          path.resolve('txt-loader.js'),
        ],
      },
    ],
/* ... */
```

You need to be careful with this one though, since the first loader that gets instanced by webpack gets to decide the options. The options you passed to all other `ts-loader`'s with the same `instance` option get **silently ignored**.

###### 3.3 Make your loader ignore `*.ts` files

The simplest option would be to just change your `txt-loader.js` to not modify `*.ts` files in case it gets called with one. It's not a clean solution but it works nonetheless :D

`txt-loader.js`:

```js
module.exports = function TxtLoader(txt) {
  // ignore .ts files
  if(this.resourcePath.endsWith('.ts'))
    return txt;

  // handle .txt files:
  return `export const TEXT: string = ${JSON.stringify(txt)}`
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the very comprehensive answer! Solution 3.2 seems the way to go. It'll be a few days until I can try it but I'll let you know.

Comment: @Thomas wow, thanks for the 500 rep bounty! <3 That's awesome :D I had a lot of fun figuring this out, hopefully it helped you to solve your problem with ts-loader :)

Comment: Yes, 3.2 solved the problem perfectly without abandoning type checks! I simply put the ts-loader config in a variable to make sure it's the same for every invocation. Better than 3.3 which of course I'd already come up with, but didn't feel right. I already set a bounty before, but it expired before you answered. Didn't seem fair :)

Comment: Thank you so much for detailed information. I'm being building a custom loader that generated TypeScript and faced the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

In your minimal repro, I found that commenting out these lines removed the problem:

```js
...
{
  test: /\.txt$/,
  use: [
    // remove ts-loader from this pipeline, and you don't get the unexpected watch behavior
    path.resolve('txt-loader.js'),
  ],
},
...
```

I think what is happening is that when you chain the `ts-loader` in your `use` array for `/\.txt$/` pipeline, it is setting watches on what it thinks is the entire typescript project, and then re-invoking the pipeline (including your custom `txt-loader`) whenever anything changes. Normally this is a good thing, because it will re-compile your project if, for example a `.d.ts` file changes that is only included implicitly through `tsconfig.json`, not through an explicit webpack-processed import statement.

At least in the simple repro you provided, the bundle seems to generate and run *without* `ts-loader` in the `/\.txt$/` pipeline at all, which might be enough to solve your problem.

But on the off chance that it's necessary for some reason in your real-world case to include `ts-loader` in this pipeline, you should be able to tell `ts-loader` to only look at/watch the explicitly bundled files by using the `onlyCompileBundledFiles` option (see [docs](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader#onlycompilebundledfiles)):

```js
...
{
  test: /\.txt$/,
  use: [
    { 
      loader: 'ts-loader',
      options: { appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.txt$/], onlyCompileBundledFiles: true },
    }
    path.resolve('txt-loader.js'),
  ],
},
...
```

Comment: Omitting the `ts-loader` for `.txt` worked because the generated code happens to be valid JavaScript as well (no types) in this simple example. I've updated the example. Passing `onlyCompileBundledFiles: true` does not seem to solve the problem; I still see `TxtLoader invoked with: declare module '*.txt'`.

Comment: Also added throwing an exception in the loader, to make the problem more apparent.

Comment: Weird. It looks non-deterministic on my end - I'll take a closer look.

Comment: I think Webpack adds some parallelism, so the order in which the files are processed differs, but in my case there are always extra files being passed through the loader upon re-build.